# How many points needed to compute the Homography?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, geometry

I'm working on a project where i'm using planar homography.

[image]

As seen in the above image, every point gives two equations and since the homography matrix has 8 degree of freedom, 4 points are enough to solve the H-matrix.

However, if if look at the two equations every point gives, we see that we also need to know x,y of the corresponding point.

So my question is in this case:

Do we need **four points** or **four pairs** to compute the homography?? and isn't it more precise to say four pair of points are needed instead of four points??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the transformed points, you have no equation at all !

Indeed, you need four pairs of *corresponding* points.